# C/C++ equivalent for Matlab's imtransform?

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing

Is there something equivalent to matlab's imtransform in C++? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the code for imtransform in matlab, and I'm trying to use or rewrite it in C++.

edit: Not built into C++, but any libraries that you may know of which would do the same thing would be great

Comment: Do you mean C xor C++ ? These are two different languages.

Comment: C++, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).  I don't remember whether it has that exact transform, but it has a lot of related code to take a look at (it's open source).

Answer (score 0):

No. Neither ISO C nor ISO C++ define any kind of image manipulation functions or formats (even including C1X and C++0x). (Your platform or operating system might though)